# Does java have a clamp function?

Tags: java, clamp

Suppose I have a `value`, I usually do this to "clamp" it to a range, here the range `[0..1]`. That is if it is below the range start, increase it to the range start, it above the range end, reduce it to the range end.

```
clampedValue = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, value));
```

Is there any built in function for clamping to a range?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza [HLSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_shader_language)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683442/where-can-i-find-the-clamp-function-in-net ?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Also [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/clamp.xml)

Comment: @AdamGent thanks, but that's c#

Comment: @weston it looks pretty trivial to write your own (ie just translate the c#).

Comment: @AdamGent It's clearly trivial to right my own function, I have the code right in the question there. I'd rather use one that's built in, particularly because that would deal with all value datatypes probably.

Comment: I don't really know your level of expertise java so it's hard for me to assume your knowledge. The c # uses Comparable to handle multiple data types.... Guess what you do in Java :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Yes, it's built in from Java 21](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#clamp(long,long,long)).

Overloads are provided for float, double, int and long.

Answer (score 199):

Edit, fall 2023: this answer is obsolete! Please see [this much-more-recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75707634/139010) for information as of Java 21.

---

> Is there any built in function for clamping to a range?

No.

Comment: For future visitors: this is changing. See [Michael Berry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75707634/4151129).

Answer (score 56):

Having looked at the generic clamp method offered up in another answer, it is worth noting that this has [boxing/unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) considerations for primitive types.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T clamp(T val, T min, T max) {...}

float clampedValue = clamp(value, 0f, 1f);
```

This will use the `Float` wrapper class, resulting in 3 box operations, one for each parameter, and 1 unbox operation for the returned type.

To avoid this, I would just stick to writing it long hand or use a non-generic function for the type you want:

```
public static float clamp(float val, float min, float max) {
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, val));
}
```

Then just overload with identical methods for every primitive type you require.

Answer (score 27):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) includes [`Ints.constrainToRange()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#constrainToRange-int-int-int-) (and equivalent methods for the other primitives). From the [release notes](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release21#commonprimitives):

> added `constrainToRange([type] value, [type] min, [type] max)` methods which constrain the given value to the closed range defined by the `min` and `max` values. They return the value itself if it's within the range, the `min` if it's below the range and the `max` if it's above the range.

Comment: For those that use Apache commons lang3 and not Guava, there is the Range.fit method.

`Range.between(0.0, 1.0).fit(0.5); // returns 0.5`

Comment: They added this in 3.10: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/changes-report.html#a3.10

Answer (score 17):

Ported from [a .NET answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683442/where-can-i-find-the-clamp-function-in-net):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T clamp(T val, T min, T max) {
    if (val.compareTo(min) < 0) return min;
    else if (val.compareTo(max) > 0) return max;
    else return val;
}
```

**Caution:** Unlike .NET, primitive types are not allowed in generics, which means they must be boxed/unboxed. When working with primitive types, such as `int` and `double`, this implementation will perform three box operations and one unbox operation.

*Note: since it’s a port of [the .NET answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683442/where-can-i-find-the-clamp-function-in-net), I made this a community wiki post.*

Answer (score 13):

Another not so pretty, but possible solution is to use the ternary operator, which is a shorthand for the `if-then-else` statement.

Some Examples:

```
// value must be between MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE
value = value > MAX_VALUE ? MAX_VALUE : value < MIN_VALUE ? MIN_VALUE : value;

// value must be between 0 and 10
value = value > 10 ? 10 : value < 0 ? 0 : value;
```

Comment: I like this one-liner. It's concise!

Comment: I ran several thousand iterations of this, versus the original method provided by @weston and this seems to be taking about 3/4ths of the time to calculate. Definitely more efficient than using Min/Max functions.

Answer (score 2):

This may be unrelated to the question, but if someone's looking for the same feature in javafx or kotlin, as I was, here they are:

javafx:

```
Utils.clamp(min, value, max)
```

kotlin:

```
value.coerceIn(min, max)
```