# What's the simplest way to bound a value to a range in Java?

Tags: java, logic

I have a numeric value myX that I want to bound to some range [X_MIN, X_MAX]. I don't care whether myX is within that range or not, I just want to make it so.

Obviously this works:

```
if(myX < X_MIN) {
  myX = X_MIN;
} else if (myX > X_MAX) {
  mX = X_MAX;
}
```

as does this:

```
myX = Math.max(X_MIN, Math.min(myX, X_MAX));
```

The first is too verbose and the meaning of the second isn't immediately obvious. Is there another simple, explicit way to do this? Solutions using Guava, Commons, etc are welcome.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656651/does-java-have-a-clamp-function

Comment: Ah, "clamp" - that's why my search didn't return anything useful.

Comment: Guava recently introduced [`Ints.constrainToRange()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#constrainToRange-int-int-int-) to address this.