# I am trying to create a Clamp method in java

Tags: java, clamp

Hey so I am trying to code a random delay using a minimum ms delay, maximum ms delay and some other calculations. For this I need to clamp some integers and a long. Below is a class that I called MathUtil to try to code a Clamp.

```
public static long clamp(long delayPreClamp, int min, int max) {
    return 90;
}
```

The numbers it is using you can find below:

```
double deviation = 22;
                    double mean = 90;
                    int min = 43;
                    int max = 198;
                    Random r = new Random();
                    double randGauss = (r.nextGaussian() * deviation);
                    long delayPreClamp = Math.round(randGauss + mean);
                    long delay = (long) MathUtil.clamp(delayPreClamp, min, max);
```

My issue is that in the first mentioned code, I can only return min, max, delayPreClamp or a number. I need it to create a new number that will be the delay.

Comment: Unable to understand your problem. Please reframe your question.

Comment: **Edited** Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Do you mean to generate a random number between min/max like `rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min`

Comment: yes but also utilising delayPreClamp

Comment: It is still kind of unclear what you are attempting, however, it may be possible that this is the answer you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16659144/6626496

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does java have a clamp function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656651/does-java-have-a-clamp-function)

Comment: No not a duplicate, I am making a clamp method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Clamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_(graphics))

```
public static long clamp(long delayPreClamp, int min, int max) {
    // v = delayPreClamp
    // if v < min, returns the greater between min and v, thus min
    // if v > max, returns the greater between min and max, thus max
    // if v is between min and max, returns the greater between min and v, thus v
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(delayPreclamp, max));
}
```