# create vertical JDesktopPane at the left side of Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdesktoppane, vertical-partitioning

i want to create a vertical JDesktopPane thus when a JInternalFrame minimizes its icon adds at the left side of Jframe and vertically below other icons not next to the previous icons and horizontally. it may be the same as linux or mac desktopPane that their desktopPane is at the left side of screen not at the bottom.

Comment: I think you'll need a custom `DesktopPaneUI`.

Comment: would you tell me how i can create one because i can not find it anywhere?
thank you

Comment: The supported L&Fs are [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/).

Comment: thanks you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You should probably create a custom `DesktopManager`. The DesktopManager is responsible for managing the desktop. In particular you would want to extend the DefaultDesktopManager as it provides the current support for positioning the buttons of the minimized internal frames.

In particular I would think you need to override the `getBoundsForIconOf(...)` method and probably the `getPreviousBounds(...)`. You could look at the source code to see how it works for the horizontal layout and modify the code for your vertical layout.

This posting has a little example to get you started: //stackoverflow.com/questions/18433475/jdesktoppane-minimising-jinternalframes. Normally when you maximize an internal frame it will cover any iconified buttons. The custom code will only maximize the internal frame to the top of the iconified buttons.

Comment: thank you for your response i think this is the right way...but whenever i override DesktopManager functions it throw null pointer exception

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at
javax.swing.RepaintManager.getVolatileOffscreenBuffer(RepaintManager.java:1030)
 at
javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1489)
com.apple.laf.AquaInternalFrameDockIconUI$ScaledImageLabel.updateI on(AquaInternalFrameDockIconUI.java:193)
at
com.apple.laf.AquaInternalFrameDockIconUI$ScaledImageLabel.paint(AquaInternalFrameDockIconUI.java:204)

Comment: i mean as i set DesktopManager() i receive a null pointer exception when i minimize internalJframe
just like this issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774432/exception-in-the-iconization-of-jinternalframe-with-defaultdesktopmanager

Comment: I gave you a link containing working code. Did you copy and try the code? Does it have an Exception?

Comment: yes i copy that code. but as i said whenever i set DesktopManager a null pointer exception has been thrown.

Comment: Well I don't use Apple so I don't know what the problem is. Maybe you need to extend the Apple DesktopManager, (instead of the DefaultDesktopManager) whatever the class is that Apple uses.

Comment: You don't need to search just add `System.out.println(desktopPane.getDesktopManager());` to your code to see what class is being used as the desktop manager.